# DataTable to given type T simple mapper

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net, properties

I threw this together and would love any suggestions on how to improve on this simple `DataTable` to given Type `T` mapper. Anything from coding conventions to speed optimizations or "you're doing something stupid".

```
public class test {

  static ISXLog log = new XLog();

  public void runTest() {
    var data = RetrieveDataSet(/*parameters not important*/);
    AddressType[] addr = mapObjects<AddressType>(data.Tables[0]);                                                               
  }

  // overload for optional function parameter
  public static T[] mapObjects<T>(DataTable dt ) where T : new(){
    return mapObjects<T>(dt, (p => p.IsCollection()));
  }

  // mapObjects from DataTable to Type T
  public static T[] mapObjects<T>(DataTable dt, Func<PropertyInfo,bool>propRestriction) where T : new() {
  T[] newobjs;
  var Rows = dt.Rows;
  newobjs = new T[Rows.Count];
  var MField = typeof(DataRowExtensions)
    .GetMethod(@"Field", new[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });

  for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++) {
    DataRow dbobj = Rows[i];
    var obj = newobjs[i] = new T();
    var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in objProps) {
      try {
        if (!dbobj.Table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name) || propRestriction(prop)) {
          log.Debug("Nothing to set for property: {0}", prop.Name);
        }else{
          MField = MField.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
            .MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType);

          var objval = MField.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbobj, prop.Name });
          prop.SetValue(obj, objval, null);
          log.Debug("Set property '{0}' to value '{1}'", prop.Name, objval);

        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        log.DebugException("Error occured while trying to set prop: " + prop.Name, e);
      }
    }
  }
  return newobjs;
}

  public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
  {
    public static bool IsCollection(this PropertyInfo property) {
      return (!typeof(String).Equals(property.PropertyType) &&
        typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**
Methodnames should be using `PascalCase` based on the [Method Naming Guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) so

```
public static T[] mapObjects<T>()
```

should be

```
public static T[] MapObjects<T>()
```

or better, as the method is mapping datarows of a datatable **to** objects T

```
public static T[] MapTo<T>()
```

Variables should be using `camelCase` and should be as descriptive as possible, so they are readable/understandable for Mr.Maintainer.

```
T[] newobjs;
var Rows = dt.Rows;
DataRow dbobj = Rows[i];
```

should be e.g

```
T[] newObjs;
var rows = dt.Rows;
DataRow row = rows[i];
```

**Bug**

```
var Rows = dt.Rows;
newobjs = new T[Rows.Count];
```

You are creating a new array of `T` whichs dimension is 1 to big. This should be

```
var Rows = dt.Rows;
newobjs = new T[Rows.Count -1];
```

but now you also need to check for the `Rows.Count`property if it is 0.

**Avoidable problems**

- As the method having a `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>` property is public, you should check if the parameter is `null`
- A retrieved columnvalue also can be DBNull, insert a DBNull check

**Optimization**

- As the columns of the datatable won't change you don't need to query them for each
  datarow
- This should be an extension method for `DataTable`

After taking all this, the refactored methods will result in

```
public class TestDataTableExtensions
{
    public static void runTest()
    {
        var data = RetrieveDataSet(/*parameters not important*/);
        AddressType[] addr = data.Tables[0].MapTo<AddressType>();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    private static ILogger log = Logger.GetLogger();
    public static T[] MapTo<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : new()
    {
        return dt.MapTo<T>(p => p.IsCollection());
    }

    public static T[] MapTo<T>(this DataTable dt, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> propertyRestriction) where T : new()
    {
        T[] mappedObjects = null;
        var rows = dt.Rows;

        if (rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return mappedObjects;
        }

        mappedObjects = new T[rows.Count - 1];

        var methodInfo = typeof(DataRowExtensions)
          .GetMethod(@"Field", new[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });

        DataColumnCollection columns = dt.Columns;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = rows[i];
            var currentObject = mappedObjects[i] = new T();
            var properties = currentObject.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                String propertyName = property.Name;
                try
                {
                    if (!columns.Contains(propertyName) || 
                        (propertyRestriction != null && propertyRestriction(property)))
                    {
                        log.Debug("Nothing to set for property: {0}", propertyName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        methodInfo = methodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
                          .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);

                        var objval = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { row, propertyName });
                        property.SetValue(currentObject,
                            DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? value : null,
                            null);

                        log.Debug("Set property '{0}' to value '{1}'", propertyName, objval);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.DebugException("Error occured while trying to set prop: " + property.Name, e);
                }
            }
        }
        return mappedObjects;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool IsCollection(this PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return (!typeof(String).Equals(property.PropertyType) &&
          typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Debug(String message, params Object[] objects);
    void DebugException(String message, Exception e);
}
public class Logger:ILogger
{
    private static ISXLog logger = new XLog();
    public static ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        return new Logger();
    }

    void ILogger.Debug(string message, params object[] objects)
    {
        logger.Debug(message, objects);
    }

    void ILogger.DebugException(string message, Exception e)
    {
        logger.DebugException(message, e);
    }
}
```

I just couldn't resist to beautyfy this and therefor I lend the following parts from [paritosh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13700/paritosh)'s answer.
**If you, the OP, consider to mark my answer because of the parts lend from [paritosh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13700/paritosh)'s answer then don't do it.**

> ```
> var mappedObjectProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
>                                    .Where(elem => !propRestriction(elem)).ToList();
> var mappedObjectCollection = new List<T>();
> ```

After renaming `mappedObjectProperties` to `properties` (also it is a good name), adjusting `propRestriction` to fit the parametername of our implementation and renaming `mappedObjectCollection` to `mappedObjects`, we need to add a check if `propertyRestriction != null`.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties =
    ((propertyRestriction != null) ?
    typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(elem => !propertyRestriction(elem)) :
    typeof(T).GetProperties());
```

But as always we can do better. Why shouldn't we restrict the properties to only the columnnames of the datatable ?

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties =
    ((propertyRestriction != null) ?
    typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(elem => !propertyRestriction(elem)) :
    typeof(T).GetProperties())
    .Where(prop => dt.Columns.Contains(prop.Name));
```

Next we add a check if either `!properties.Any()` or `dt.Rows.Count == 0` and if one of these checks will be true, we are finished.

But, why shouldn't we add an extension method for a `DataRow` ? We just do it.
As we need the name of the property to access the value of the datacolumn and also for logging we add a `String propertyName`

```
    public static T MapTo<T>(this DataRow dataRow, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T currentObject = new T();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            String propertyName = property.Name;
            try
            {
                var value = dataRow[propertyName];
                property.SetValue(currentObject,
                    DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? value : null,
                    null);
                log.Debug("Set property '{0}' to value '{1}'", propertyName, value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.DebugException("Error occured while trying to set prop: " + property.Name, e);
            }
        }

        return currentObject;
    }
}
```

Now we can simplify the `DataTable`'s extension method to

```
    public static T[] MapTo<T>(this DataTable dt, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> propertyRestriction) where T : new()
    {
        IList<T> mappedObjects = new List<T>();

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties =
            ((propertyRestriction != null) ?
            typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(elem => !propertyRestriction(elem)) :
            typeof(T).GetProperties())
            .Where(prop => dt.Columns.Contains(prop.Name));

        if (!properties.Any() || dt.Rows.Count == 0) { return mappedObjects.ToArray(); }

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            mappedObjects.Add(dataRow.MapTo<T>(properties));
        }

        return mappedObjects.ToArray();
    }
```

Here we go..

```
public static class DataMappingExtensions
{
    private static ILogger log = Logger.GetLogger();

    public static T[] MapTo<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : new()
    {
        return dt.MapTo<T>(null);
    }

    public static T[] MapTo<T>(this DataTable dt, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> propertyRestriction) where T : new()
    {
        IList<T> mappedObjects = new List<T>();

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties =
            ((propertyRestriction != null) ?
            typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(elem => !propertyRestriction(elem)) :
            typeof(T).GetProperties())
            .Where(prop => dt.Columns.Contains(prop.Name));

        if (!properties.Any() || dt.Rows.Count == 0) { return mappedObjects.ToArray(); }

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            mappedObjects.Add(dataRow.MapTo<T>(properties));
        }

        return mappedObjects.ToArray();
    }

    public static T MapTo<T>(this DataRow dataRow, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T currentObject = new T();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            String propertyName = property.Name;
            try
            {
                var value = dataRow[propertyName];
                property.SetValue(currentObject,
                    !DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? value : null,
                    null);
                log.Debug("Set property '{0}' to value '{1}'", propertyName, value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.DebugException("Error occured while trying to set prop: " + property.Name, e);
            }
        }

        return currentObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort put into your answer. Why Pascal? I thought only classes should be Pascal and everything else should be cammel. I can't change the logger im using but I think it does have your suggestions I will change my usage. Thank you for your examples I will try to learn from them. It may take a few more poundings but I will learn. :) thank you!

Comment: @Archangel33 only `Parameter` and `Protected instance fields` should be `camelCased` check this link down the page [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Oops sorry missed the link.

Comment: I believe your code for the `DBNull` check is missing a `!`. It should be `!DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? value : null` or `DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? null : value` instead of `DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? value : null`

Comment: @Archangel33 You are right. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can minimize you code taking out the filtering out side of loop.
2. Avoid catching exception inside a loop if it needed ,(it seems like it cannot be avoided here)
3. No need to invoke datarow extension method to get value , you can get it directly.
4. Naming of variable is really bad.

This is first round of re factoring.

```
public static T[] MapObjects<T>(DataTable dataTable, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> 
 propRestriction) where T : new()
{
var mappedObjectProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                       .Where(elem => !propRestriction(elem)).ToList();
var mappedObjectCollection = new List<T>();
foreach (var dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var mappedObject = new T();
    foreach (var mappedObjectProperty in mappedObjectProperties)
    {
        if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(mappedObjectProperty.Name))
        {
            var value = dataRow[mappedObjectProperty.Name];
            mappedObjectProperty.SetValue(mappedObject, value, null);
        }
        else
        {
            log.Debug("Nothing to set for property: {0}", prop.Name);
        }
    }
    mappedObjectCollection.Add(mappedObject);
  }
  return mappedObjectCollection.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: ha ha it took me 10 min to finalize that name , still I am not feeling good, you have any suggestion , I would love to steal from you :)

Comment: I don't want to steal the name, but the idea behind.

Comment: oh okay gotcha lolz,

Comment: Thank you for your critique, I don't know where my head was when trying to invoke the `DataTable`'s extension method. O_o Looks like I have to work on my naming conventions and try for better ones more naturally.